# Join 3 or more tables with aggregate on one table based on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables as following:

Table `policyTable`.

`policy_id     employee_id    policy_start_date    premium
   1000001         2000001           2010-03-24      560.1
   1000002         2000003           2013-11-01      865.6
   1000023         2000201           2012-03-07      435.2
       ...             ...        ...`

Table `employeeTable`.

`employee_id    department_id    job_title_key    start_date      end_date
     2000001                5             1248    2009-05-01    2009-09-23
     2000001                5             1248    2009-09-23    2010-02-01
     2000001                3             1302    2010-02-01    2011-06-15
     2000003                4             2054    2008-03-01    2009-05-12
     2000003                4             2054    2009-05-12    2012-01-13
     2000003                4             2054    2012-01-13    2014-02-09
     2000003                7             5023    2014-02-09    NULL
     2000201                2             3125    2010-03-06    2012-01-05
     2000201                2             3125    2012-01-05    2013-08-07
     2000201                5             1265    2013-08-07    2015-02-20
     ...`

Table `departmentTable`:

`department_id    department_name
            2            finance
            3         accounting
            4           software
            5              sales
            7          marketing
          ...                ...`

My goal is to join these tables to get one record for each policy with the columns `policy_id, employee_id, policy_start_date, premium, job_title_key, department_name`. My problem right now is with `employeeTable`, which has multiple records for each employee for different job titles. I only need to get one record for each employee for each policy. The criteria is to choose the one that `policy_start_date` falls in between the employee `start_date` and `end_date`.

So my final desired table is:

`policy_id employee_id policy_start_date premium job_title_key department_name
   1000001     2000001        2010-03-24   560.1          1302      accounting
   1000002     2000003        2013-11-01   865.6          2054        software
   1000023     2000201        2012-03-07   435.2          3125         finance
       ...         ...               ...     ...           ...             ...`

I've tried to use `SELECT AGGREGATE GROUP BY` with joins, but every column that does not get aggregated needs to go in `GROUP BY`, which does not work for me here.

Comment: what is the deal with `job_title_key` and `department_name` how an employeed have different entries there?

Comment: `job_title_key` and `department_name` could be different because the employee changed status. For example, he or she could be promoted, or transitioned in the company, and their job title would change. Same thing could happen with department.

Comment: 1302's department name should be accounting?

Comment: @Beth, I corrected that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e264/4)**

```
SELECT p.policy_id, e.employee_id, p.policy_start_date, e.job_title_key, d.department_name
FROM policyTable p
INNER JOIN employeeTable e 
   on p.employee_id = e.employee_id
   and p.policy_start_date between e.start_date 
                               and CASE 
                                     WHEN e.end_date IS NULL THEN GETDATE()
                                     ELSE e.end_date
                                   END
INNER JOIN departmentTable d
   on e.department_id = d.department_id
```

Comment: I made a change to include the case when `end_date` is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
    with order
    (With Employee_correction as (select 
    employee_id ,   department_id  ,  job_title_key  ,  start_date    , 
    (case when   end_date is null then GETDATE ( ) else end_date end) as end_date
    from employeeTable)
    select policy_id, employee_id ,
    max(policy_start_date) as policy_start_date 
     from policyTable a
    join Employee_correction b on a.employee_is=b.employee_id
    and policy_start_date between start_date and end_date group by policy_id, employee_id )
    select c.policy_id ,c.employee_id ,c.policy_start_date,c.job_title_key,premium,department_name from employeeTable c
    join order on   order.policy_id=c.policy_id
 and order.employee_id=c.employee_id 
 and order.policy_start_date=c.policy_start_date
    join policyTable d on
 order.policy_id=d.policy_id and  
  order.employee_id=d.employee_id 
  and order.policy_start_date=d.policy_start_date
   join departmentTable e on c.department_id=e.department_id
```

I've made a correction for Employee assuming that when max date is null so the date is today.
In addition , to avoid duplicates, I made max aggregation on date.